# How get device location using action builder

Tags: assistant, actionbuilder

i'm writing to you to ask a little support about an action that we are currently developing using Action Builder and webhook library @assistant/conversation for Nodejs.

In particular, we would invoke our webhook's logic using the device location.
We have understand that we must ask the user permission to access on device location using something like this:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/PermissionValueSpec
but in all Github examples provided by Google nothing is specified.

Furthermore, we tried to integrate the PermissionValueSpec in a slot using the notification actions.type.Notifications, but the returned value of that slot is
PermissionLocation --> ALREADY_GRANTED without any other information about the device coordinates.

We've read a lot of documentation and also looked for some example to support our develop but nothing was found.
How we can get the current device location?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you heard from anyone about this? I'm having the same issue trying to get the device location using @assistant/conversation and all the examples I've found so far use the actions-on-google library and the dialogFlow object to ask for permissions. Can you please tell me what did you do?

Comment: are you using interactive canvas in your project?